# Bootstrap Modal Form validation on submit deleting ajax data showen inside modal

Tags: validation, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

[This is my bootstrap modal form, the from date and to date data I am passing data-*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9R9g.jpg)

[The issue is when I submit the form without any input the validation works but the from date and to date disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lt9wh.jpg)

Comment: I don't understand your question completely but i guess your page might be getting refreshed each time when you are submitting the form due to error in your ajax implementation.

Comment: Can you please show us what you have done so far??? Like show us the code that you have done.